# Opengl 2.0 glColor4f not working

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I'm creating a view using GLKit to experiment with opengl in iOS. The view has the following load method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!self.context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

}
```

And in a draw method for a shape I have the following code:

```
float vertices[] = {
    -1, -1,
    1, -1,
    0,  1};

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(vertices));

glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
```

This code will draw a triangle in the center of the screen, however the triangle is white. I set the current color to green with the line `glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)` but this does not change the current drawing color. How can I change the color of the triangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL 2.0 uses shaders to rasterize the geometry. You need to tell your shader what color you want to see. The way to do this is usually to set the color attribute of the vertices to what you want, I haven't used GLKit but I see that it has a `GLKVertexAttribColor`. Try setting it to the color you want with:

```
GLfloat triangle_colors[] = {
    1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
};

glVertexAttribPointer(
    GLKVertexAttribColor, // attribute
    4,                 // number of elements per vertex, here (r,g,b,a
    GL_FLOAT,          // the type of each element
    GL_FALSE,          // take our values as-is
    0,                 // no extra data between each position
    triangle_colors
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`glColor4f` is not an ES 2.0 call. You must have pulled in an ES 1.0 header file to get that to compile.

The easiest approach if you just want to use a solid color is to define a `uniform` variable in your shader, and pass in your color as a uniform. Or you can make the color an additional vertex attribute.

If you're using pre-baked shaders provided by GLKit, you should be able to pass in colors using `GLKVertexAttribColor`, very similar to the way you specify your vertex positions with `GLKVertexAttribPosition`.